# Stop HyperLinkField from converting URLs to relative paths in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `HyperLinkField` in a `GridView` containing a path in `DataNavigateUrlFormatString`. The path specified is just `edit.aspx`. However when I view the webpage in the browser, I see it being converted to a relative path like `../../../admin/post/edit.aspx`.

Is there any way to stop this conversion from happening. I would like it to remain as is. I even tried .`/edit.aspx`. This too gets converted. Putting the absolute part `/admin/post/edit.aspx` worked. But I don't want to specify the complete path.

Thanks

Comment: did you looked at generated html, I presume that browser adds relative path when you hover over the link or click it

Comment: Yes I looked at the HTML code. This is what the code has href="../../../_template/app/admin/post/edit.aspx". This only happens on my live web server. On my local development PC, it looks fine. I host on GoDaddy

Answer (score 0):

@Arun : this link might help you
1) http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2004/05/05/avoiding-problems-with-relative-and-absolute-urls-in-asp-net.aspx
2) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne
You can also use `ResolveClientUrl("~/Home.aspx")`